# how to remove blank lines from a file range in shell

Tags: sed

I have a file like this:

```
something

import (
    "foo1"
    "foo2"
    "foo3"

    "bar"

    "baz"
 )

something

something
```

I would like a shell command that as result will change the file to:

```
something

import (
    "foo1"
    "foo2"
    "foo3"
    "bar"
    "baz"
 )

something

something
```

Or with other words to remove the empty lines in the range of `import (` to the closing `)` and to leave the empty lines before and after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` is appropriate for this:

```
sed '/^import/,/^[[:space:]]*)/ { /^[[:space:]]*$/ d; }'
```

This command instructs `sed` to delete (`d`) every empty line (`/^[[:space:]]*$/`) located inside blocks of lines that start from "import" and end with a closing parenthesis (`/^import/,/^[[:space:]]*)/`)

Comment: I am trying this on mac and I get: sed: 1: "/^import/,/^[[:space:]] ...": extra characters at the end of d command

Comment: @gsf Can you test it with a semicolon between `d` and `}` please?

Comment: Thanks a lot - this` '/^import/,/^[[:space:]]*)/ { /^[[:space:]]*$/ d; }' ` works